# Storing an array returned from method in java

Tags: java, arrays, google-maps, methods

I want to store double dimension array returned from method. I lose my all values without the last one.

```
public static float[][]  hesap(int toplamSuc)
{       
    float[][] temp;
    temp = new float[toplamSuc][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < toplamSuc; i++) 
    {
        temp = (GGcoder.koordinat(suc[i][4], toplamSuc));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

This "temp" array stores two values. First value is crime informations. Second is latitude and langitude. I do that assignment just like below but it doesn't work.

```
float[][] temp  = new float[toplamSuc][2];
    temp = kokOlusturma.hesap(toplamSuc);
```

EDIT:The function works fine but I can't transfer the array to another array.

Comment: My temp arrays values are the same. Every values are the last one. They should be different.(latitude and longitude)

Comment: You want `temp[i] = (GGCoder...)`?

Comment: float[][] temp  = new float[toplamSuc][2];
    temp = kokOlusturma.hesap(toplamSuc);

I want to use this "temp" array's values. But it values are the same. like that --> temp[0][0] = 40 temp[0][1] = 30
                    temp[1][0] = 40 temp[1][1] = 30

Answer (score 0):

Within your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < toplamSuc; i++) 
{
    temp = (GGcoder.koordinat(suc[i][4], toplamSuc));
}
```

You are resetting `temp` on every iteration. So your `temp` variable will only have the values calculated in the last iteration of the for loop. You likely want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < toplamSuc; i++) 
{
    temp[i] = (GGcoder.koordinat(suc[i][4], toplamSuc));
}
```

Right now your method is **likely** equivalent to saying:

```
public static float[][]  hesap(int toplamSuc)
{
    float[][] temp = (GGcoder.koordinat(suc[toplamSuc-1][4], toplamSuc));
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Oh no. My temp array is double dimontional. I can take values in function but cant store another array.

Comment: @user1545283 Edited to show you what I mean. You're only returning what the last call of your `koordinat` method returns, which is not what I assume you want.